# Tensorflow - retrain inception for ethnicity recognition and hair color

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm new to tensorflow and the inception model. I found the following tutorial online (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/image_retraining/) and wanted to test this on my own project.

I'm trying to let the model recognize ethnicity based on people in a picture. I have made a training set of approx 850 images per category.

For some reason I'm unable to get more than a 65% accuracy level. I tried increasing the training steps and amount of images as well.

Maybe the inception model is not the correct model to use for this?

Could someone point me in a good direction of what I can do to improve the results?

Regards,
P.

Answer (score 2):

Do you get 65% accuracy on the train or on the test set?
If it is on the train set, you are probably doing something wrong with your code. 
If it is on the test set, you are indeed using the wrong model. The Inception model is a very very big model, and having only 850 images per category won't give you a good general model. It will simply "remember" those 850 images. (think of remembering the answer to each question on a test, instead of learning for a test)

Maybe you can try building a simpler, smaller model first and see how well that model learns!